# How can I keep running the function while pressing at the same time button1 or button2 so i can have at the end a value for self.k?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to keep running a function (named function) while at the same time clicking on button1 or button2 several times to execute the if statements and add a value to `self.k`. It doesn't work usually in python when we use `input()` the code stop and wait till the user enter an input but in Kivy, I don't know something similar.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
class example(App):
    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
        self.ques1 = "Click yes or no"
        self.begin = Label(text=self.ques1)
        self.window.add_widget(self.begin)
        self.window2 = GridLayout()
        self.window2.cols = 2
        self.window.add_widget(self.window2)
        self.button1 = Button(text="yes")
        self.window2.add_widget(self.button1)
        self.button1.bind(on_press=self.yes)
        self.button2 = Button(text="no")
        self.window2.add_widget(self.button2)
        self.button2.bind(on_press=self.no)
        #self.function(True)
        return self.window

    def yes(self, instance):
        self.ques1 = "yes"

    def no(self, instance):
        self.ques1 = "no"

    def function(self, instance):
        if self.ques1 == "yes":
            self.ques1 = "are you sure?"
            self.begin.text = self.ques1
            if self.ques1 == "yes":
                self.k = 2
            elif self.ques1 == "no":
                self.k = 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    example().run()
```

[image: Here's the output I got]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, you are new here, so just a friendly tip, it's best practice to paste your code as text instead of as an image, that way, we can help you better. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Raed Ali , I edited my question and now im waiting for and answer hope somone can answer me

Comment: It seems you want to keep the UI active while doing other jobs. If that's the case, you can run UI on `MainThread` while using another [`thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) (or maybe [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)) for that job. That way your UI will not be blocked while performing another tasks at the same time.

Comment: @ApuCoder actually no i just want to keep the if statements on stand-by till i click on one of the buttons,like it would happend if I used the input() command,because in the case of using input() the if statements don't run untill a user promt an input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, I get it now, you can achieve this by calling the method `function()` at the end of `yes()` and `no()`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class example(App):
    question2 = False

    def build(self):
        self.window = GridLayout()
        self.window.cols = 1
        self.ques1 = "Click yes or no"
        self.begin = Label(text=self.ques1)
        self.window.add_widget(self.begin)
        self.window2 = GridLayout()
        self.window2.cols = 2
        self.window.add_widget(self.window2)
        self.button1 = Button(text="yes")
        self.window2.add_widget(self.button1)
        self.button1.bind(on_press=self.yes)
        self.button2 = Button(text="no")
        self.window2.add_widget(self.button2)
        self.button2.bind(on_press=self.no)
        # self.function(True)
        return self.window

    def yes(self, instance):
        self.ques1 = "yes"
        self.function(instance)

    def no(self, instance):
        self.ques1 = "no"
        self.function(instance)

    def function(self, instance):
        if self.ques1 == "yes" and not self.question2:
            self.begin.text = "Are you sure?"
            self.question2 = True
        elif self.ques1 == "yes" and self.question2:
            self.k = 2
            print(self.k)
        elif self.ques1 == "no" and self.question2:
            self.k = 1
            print(self.k)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    example().run()
```

Please tell me if I interpreted your question correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I prefer more if there was a way to run the function named function in background while clicking on buttons yes and no because this problem here is a tiny part of my big problem and my full code contains alot of if conditions so you see i need a way to handle them all

Comment: @GhachiSami I'm not sure if I can get a function to do that, but if you could put the full code in your question, I might be able to find something that works.

Comment: basically its a tree of if statements and its alot over 300 line,im not sure if it can be posted here that's why i gived this tiny problem because the logic is the same so i need a way to keep the if statements on stand-by till i click on the button 1 or button 2

Comment: @GhachiSami Don't worry, that will fit, if you send it I might be able to optimise it

Comment: unfortuantely i tried the same thing but it wont work,its true that the first layer of condition will execute then it would never reach the second layer and thus self.k will never receive a value.

Comment: @GhachiSami You're right, I edited the code again and used a boolean variable to reach the second layer.

Comment: thank you alot, you was so helpfull its now fonctional and really cover my needs.Now gonna try to use this logic on a bigger scale,thanks again.

Comment: @GhachiSami Glad to have helped, could you mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: done,thanks again have a nice day